# Is is possible to have custom fields in CloudWatch Logs from my application's logs?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have several NodeJS applications running on ECS Fargate and the logs are being shipped to CloudWatch. I'd like to have custom fields show up in CloudWatch for each log message such as application.name and application.version and possibly ones created depending on the content of the log message. Say my log message is `[ERROR] Prototype: flabebes-flower crashed` and I'd like to pull out the log level `ERROR` and the name of the prototype `flabebes-flower`. Is it possible to have these fields in CloudWatch? If so, how can I accomplish this? I know how to achieve this using Filebeat processors and shipping the logs to Elasticsearch, I have that solution already but I'd like to explore the possibility of moving away from Elasticsearch and just using CloudWatch without having to write my own parsers.

Answer (score 2):

There are basically two options:

1. If your log messages always have the same format, you can use the [parse feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html) of CloudWatch Log Insights to extract these fields, e.g.,

   ```
   parse @message "[*] Prototype: * crashed" as level, prototype
   ```
2. If the metadata that you want to extract into custom fields is not in a parsable format, you can configure your application to log in JSON format and add the metadata to the JSON log within your application (how depends on the logging library that you use). Your JSON format can then look something like this:

   ```
   {"prototype":"flabebes-flower","level":"error","message":"[ERROR] Prototype: flabebes-flower crashed","timestamp":"27.05.2022, 18:09:46"}
   ```

   Again with [CloudWatch Log Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AnalyzingLogData.html), you can access the custom fields `prototype` and `level`. CloudWatch will automatically parse the JSON for you, there is no need to use the `parse` command as in the above method.

   This allows you, e.g., to run the query

   ```
    fields @timestamp, message
    | filter level = "error"
   ```

   to get all error message.